# array_sum error in looping for PHP And MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some mysql table like this:

```
| IDPRAKTIKAN |       NAMAUSER | MODULKE | NILAI | STATUS_TUGASAKHIR | TAHUNAJARAN | SEMESTER |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       0 |     3 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       1 |    55 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       2 |    54 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       3 |    45 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       4 |    62 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081478 |   Ade Dwinanto |       5 |    20 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       0 |     3 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       1 |    55 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       2 |    53 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       3 |    47 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       4 |    60 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
|  3332081483 | Arya Prasettyo |       5 |    20 |                 1 |       09/10 |        3 |
```

**[This is my Data On MySQL (On sqlfiddle.com)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ed96/1)**

And This is My PHP Code:

```
<?php
   $setting_tahunajaranget = $_GET['setting_tahunajaran'];
   $setting_kodepraktikumget = $_GET['setting_kodepraktikum'];
   $nama_praktikum = $_GET['nama_praktikum'];
   $setting_semesterget = $_GET['setting_semester'];

$query2 = "SELECT `nilai` AS semester FROM `nilaipraktikum` WHERE `modulke`= 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$data   = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query2));
        $query = "SELECT `idpraktikan`,namauser,`modulke`, `nilai`,`status_tugasakhir`,`tahunajaran`,`semester` FROM `nilaipraktikum` LEFT JOIN tabeluser ON tabeluser.npmuser = nilaipraktikum.idpraktikan WHERE `tahunajaran` = '$setting_tahunajaranget' AND`kodepraktikum` = '$setting_kodepraktikumget' AND `semester` = '$setting_semesterget' ";


        $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)>=1)
    {

   $nilai   =   $data['nilai'];
        if ($nilai = $setting_semesterget);

echo "<table width='auto' border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='3' align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>No</strong></td>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Nama</strong></td>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>NPM</strong></td>";

        for($i=1;$i<=$jml_modul;$i++) {
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Modul Ke-".$i."</strong></td>"; 
        }

echo    "<td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Rata-Rata</strong></td>";

    if ($setting_status_ta=0)
    {
    }
    if ($setting_status_ta=1)
    {
    echo"<td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Nilai Tugas Akhir</strong></td>";
    }

echo    "<td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Nilai Akhir</strong></td>
    <td align='center' valign='middle'><strong>Grade</strong></td>
  </tr>";

        while(list($nim,$nama,$modulke,$nilai,$nilai_tugasakhir) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $array_nim[$nim] = $nim;
            $array_nama[$nim] = $nama;
            $array_nilai[$nim][$modulke]= $nilai;
            $array_nilaita[$nim][$nilai_tugasakhir]= $nilai_tugasakhir;

        }

            foreach($array_nim as $nim) {
            echo "<tr><td align='center' valign='middle'>".(++$nomor)."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".$nim."</td>";
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".$array_nama[$nim]."</td>";

            for($i=1;$i<=$jml_modul;$i++) 
            {
                echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".$array_nilai[$nim][$i]."</td>"; 
                $nilaimodul += (array_sum(array($array_nilai[$nim][$i])));

            }
                            $ratarata = ($nilaimodul);

            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".round ($ratarata,2)."</td>";
$ntugasakhir = $array_nilai[$nim][$jml_modul-($jml_modul-1)];


    if ($setting_status_ta=0)
    {
    }
    if ($setting_status_ta=1)
    {
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".round ($ntugasakhir,2)."</td>";
    }


$nialiakhirpraktikum = $ntugasakhir+$ratarata;
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".round ($nialiakhirpraktikum,1)."</td>";
    if ($nialiakhirpraktikum>79)
                                    $grade="A";
                                 else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=79 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>67)
                                    $grade="B";
                                 else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=67 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>55)
                                    $grade="C";
                                 else if ($nialiakhirpraktikum<=55 AND $nialiakhirpraktikum>44)
                                    $grade="D";
                                 else
                                    $grade="E"; 
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".$grade."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
            echo "<br/> <a href='javascript:history.back()'>Klik Disini Untuk Kembali</a>";

    }    
?>
```

my question, why for the Rata-Rata (is average NILAI) column summed array results with the results of the previous array?
For more details, please see the picture here. (**Link Picture: https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3gviv/3m98?size=o**)

whereas the results I want to average a column like this picture. (**Link Picture: https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3gviv/6ke4?size=o**)

what is wrong with my script?

NB: 
column Nilai Tugas Akhir    Nilai Akhir     Grade is not yet fixed.

Comment: First, you'll need to clean up your code: if ($setting_status_ta=0) .. these tests (where you use =, and not ==), assign values (and modifies the variables) and does not test for equality. After that, clean up your indentation to match your actual loops, so it becomes easier to follow your logic.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing unfiltered, unvalidated data directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: @Charles how to fix it? do you have a any idea for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add initialization variable

```
$nilaimodul = 0; // try adding this to your code
for($i=1;$i<=$jml_modul;$i++) 
{
    echo "<td align='center' valign='middle'>".$array_nilai[$nim][$i]."</td>"; 
    $nilaimodul += (array_sum(array($array_nilai[$nim][$i])));
}
$ratarata = ($nilaimodul);
```

Comment: Thanks @Husni,... My Problame is Solved... Many Thanks,... ^_^